# LibreSSL aes encryption incompatible with OpenSSL?

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

Machine A has OpenSSL 1.0.2k and I encrypt a dummy file like this:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in plain.txt -e -pass pass:abcd1234 -out cipher.enc
```

Machine B has LibreSSL 3.3.3 and when I decrypt the file from machine A like this:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in cipher.enc -d -pass pass:abcd1234 -out plain.txt
```

It fails to decrypt, giving this error:

> bad decrypt
> 4444794304:error:06FFF064:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad decrypt:evp/evp_enc.c:549:

Note that if I try to decrypt it using the same command line on machine A, it works fine.

I don't know how outdated OpenSSL 1.0.2k is but unfortunately I have no control over upgrading it (it's a remote 3rd party server).

Is there an incompatibility between OpenSSL and LibreSSL when using AES encryption?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution, posting here in case it helps anyone else facing the same problem.

Apparently, in a later version of OpenSSL (later LibreSSL) the default hashing algorithm for key derivation was changed from md5 to sha256.

More details here:
https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/378

So now I explicitly specify the hashing algo in both command lines. To encrypt on Machine A:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in plain.txt -e -pass pass:abcd1234 -md sha256 -out cipher.enc
```

And to decrypt on Machine B:

```
libressl enc -aes-256-cbc -in cipher.enc -d -pass pass:abcd1234 -md sha256 -out plain.txt
```

And now it works fine.

[Edit] -- In case the default key derivation parameters may ever change in the future, or the old implicit defaults are considered insufficient at some point, perhaps it's best to explicitly define those as well. For example by including `-pbkdf2 -iter 100000`.
So then it becomes:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in plain.txt -e -pass pass:abcd1234 -md sha256 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -out cipher.enc
```

To encrypt, and to decrypt:

```
libressl enc -aes-256-cbc -in cipher.enc -d -pass pass:abcd1234 -md sha256 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -out plain.txt
```

(openssl and libressl can be used interchangeably in this way)

Comment: Thanks for this! I have various Macs some with LibreSSL 2.8 and some with 3.3+ and encrypting and decrypting between the two wasn't working. I had encrypted on the old Mac (still stuck on Monterey) and couldn't decrypt on my newer Mac (which is on Ventura). Adding -md md5 to the decrypt on my newer Mac worked.

Comment: @BenCourliss Great! I just edited my answer to add the KDF params as well, in case those ever lead to an inconsistency in future versions of either openssl or libressl.